# Show div before fixed navigation top bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed top bar, and now I need to append before this element a div to show a message.

Both should be fixed. First the alert message, and then the menu. How can i do that?

```
<div class="panel-msg">
  Important message here
</div>

<nav id=" mainNav " class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation ">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="navbar-header ">
      <h1>
      demo
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="demo ">
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sawqv3gp/)

Comment: you can add panel-msg inside mainNav  at the top

Comment: @Chiller, thanks, this solves the issue.

Comment: If it solved the issue can you mark as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` is possible only with positioning so give the class `panel-msg` absolute position and a `z-index` higher than that of `navbar` like this:

```
 .panel-msg{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:222222;
      top:0px;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't put the Alert above the NavBar like the user wants. It does when you scroll but not when the page loads.

Comment: are you using top:0px;

Comment: You are right, I didn't use top:0px. However, the alert still scrolls away. Maybe this is what the user intended for though?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you use "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" it will override any changes you make and always put that navbar at the top. If you remove the word "top" it will show the msg panel.

Here's your example with an alert message above: http://jsfiddle.net/sawqv3gp/

But it loses it's fixed positioning. So you might want to try a different layout altogether.

I would recommend changing your design to allow for a "navbar header" and using the Bootstrap alert function (also always the user to close the alert).

Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/4FSUjc2qej

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
<strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you are looking very good.
```